# cakephp save blank input type="number" giving NULL

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

I have a form with and input that has a validation rule of numeric. The input can be supplied or left blank. But when left black cakephp tried to save the value as NULL which throws a mySQL error of field

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 
 'age_group' cannot be null
```

I just an empty string and the field not to be saved.

```
    'age_group' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at this wrong. All I had to do was set each field in the database at allow null.